# stringFromDate is returning null

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code which works fine in other part of my app but I am stumped why it is not working here.

```
- (IBAction)endButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
    [timer invalidate];

    NSDateFormatter *dFormatter;
    [dFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

    NSString *currentTime_string = [dFormatter stringFromDate:currentTime];
    timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Student arrived at:  %@",  currentTime_string];



    //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backToHomeScreen" sender:self];


}
```

When i run this the label text is "Student arrived at: (null)"

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize dateFormatter

```
NSDateFormatter *dFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
```

Comment: Thank you. So i thought because of ARC alloc and init were no longer needed. Is init still necessary? why does alloc still work?

Comment: ARC doesn't allocate memory for you, it aids in cleaning up resources that are no longer needed.

Comment: Thats correct. It helps reduce memory leak which is caused if you don't release objects